# Are there any video editors in Ubuntu that can handle some of the tasks below?

Tags: video, video-editor, editing

My post is a bit vague, but I need a video editor that can do the following:

- link different video files with text transitions
- allow music in the background

I have read some posts and all the ubuntu video editors come with interfaces that are hard to use for a complete beginner to video editing.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Openshot can do it, but I don't know if you would think it is hard to use.

Comment: These sound like very basic requirements, usual suspects like openshot, pitivi should do fine.

Comment: I've been using lightshark, but it can be difficult to learn and its a freemium software.

Comment: You could also try flowblade which is programmed in python and after my tests the one less likely prone to errors, it has adocumentation and a very responsive UI.